# Exception thrown when storing the data to Ignite cache through IgniteClient

Tags: ignite

I am Java thin client (IgniteCLient) for connecting to Ignite server and get/set operations to be done server cache. When I try to store the custom object to the cache, getting below exception and the cache set is failing. If I try to store the same object using the Ignite client node, it works fine. Is there any limitation with java thin client , the types of data we can store?

Ignite server version: 2.7.6

PFB the exception trace:

```
class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Failed to serialize object [typeName=com.wyse.stratus.server.cache.ConfigurationSchemaIgniteCache]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.write(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:840)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal0(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:223)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:164)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:151)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.GridBinaryMarshaller.marshal(GridBinaryMarshaller.java:254)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.ClientBinaryMarshaller.marshal(ClientBinaryMarshaller.java:69)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.ClientUtils.writeObject(ClientUtils.java:495)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.TcpClientCache.lambda$put$1(TcpClientCache.java:105)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.TcpClientChannel.send(TcpClientChannel.java:138)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.ReliableChannel.service(ReliableChannel.java:124)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.ReliableChannel.request(ReliableChannel.java:162)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.TcpClientCache.put(TcpClientCache.java:100)
at com.wyse.stratus.server.cache.IgniteThinClient.set(IgniteThinClient.java:58)
at com.wyse.stratus.server.cache.IgniteCacheableItem.set(IgniteCacheableItem.java:107)
at com.wyse.stratus.server.cache.ConfigurationSchemaIgniteCache.setConfigurationSchema(ConfigurationSchemaIgniteCache.java:55)
at com.wyse.stratus.server.service.config.ConfigurationPackageManagerImpl.getCachedConfigurationSchema(ConfigurationPackageManagerImpl.java:122)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy323.getCachedConfigurationSchema(Unknown Source)
at com.wyse.stratus.server.bo.ConfigParameterValidatorImpl.getSchema(ConfigParameterValidatorImpl.java:110)
at com.wyse.stratus.server.bo.ConfigParameterValidatorImpl.validateConfigParameterGroup(ConfigParameterValidatorImpl.java:119)
at com.wyse.stratus.server.bo.ConfigurationManager20Impl.getGroupConfigSettingsForUI(ConfigurationManager20Impl.java:1241)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy328.getGroupConfigSettingsForUI(Unknown Source)
at com.wyse.stratus.server.web.facade.ConfigurationFacadeImpl.getGroupDeviceTypeSetting(ConfigurationFacadeImpl.java:485)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:69)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy381.getGroupDeviceTypeSetting(Unknown Source)
at com.wyse.stratus.server.web.controller.GroupController.getGroupSummary(GroupController.java:617)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilter(ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.java:59)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at com.wyse.stratus.server.security.LocaleContextFilter.doFilterInternal(LocaleContextFilter.java:46)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:121)
at com.wyse.stratus.server.security.StratusPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(StratusPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:246)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
at com.wyse.stratus.server.security.StratusLogoutFilter.doFilter(StratusLogoutFilter.java:85)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.RestCsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(RestCsrfPreventionFilter.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:791)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Failed to write field [name=cache]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor.write(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:164)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.write(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:809)
... 149 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Failed to serialize object [typeName=org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.TcpClientCache]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.write(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:840)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal0(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:223)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:164)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:151)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.doWriteObject(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:515)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.writeObjectField(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:1185)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor$DefaultFinalClassAccessor.write0(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:687)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor.write(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:157)
... 150 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Failed to write field [name=ch]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor.write(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:164)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.write(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:809)
... 157 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Failed to serialize object [typeName=org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.ReliableChannel]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.write(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:840)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal0(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:223)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:164)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:151)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.doWriteObject(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:515)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.writeObjectField(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:1185)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor$DefaultFinalClassAccessor.write0(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:687)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor.write(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:157)
... 158 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Failed to write field [name=ch]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor.write(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:164)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.write(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:809)
... 165 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Failed to serialize object [typeName=org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.TcpClientChannel]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.write(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:840)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal0(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:223)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:164)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:151)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.doWriteObject(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:515)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.writeObjectField(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:1185)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor$DefaultFinalClassAccessor.write0(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:687)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor.write(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:157)
... 166 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Failed to write field [name=sock]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor.write(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:164)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.write(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:809)
... 173 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Failed to serialize object [typeName=java.net.Socket]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.write(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:840)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal0(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:223)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:164)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:151)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.doWriteObject(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:515)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.writeObjectField(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:1185)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor$DefaultFinalClassAccessor.write0(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:687)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor.write(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:157)
... 174 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Failed to write field [name=impl]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor.write(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:164)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.write(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:809)
... 181 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Failed to serialize object [typeName=java.net.SocksSocketImpl]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.write(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:840)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal0(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:223)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:164)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:151)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.doWriteObject(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:515)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.writeObjectField(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:1185)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor$DefaultFinalClassAccessor.write0(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:687)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor.write(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:157)
... 182 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Failed to write field [name=socketInputStream]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor.write(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:164)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.write(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:809)
... 189 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Failed to serialize object [typeName=java.net.SocketInputStream]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.write(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:840)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal0(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:223)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:164)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:151)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.doWriteObject(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:515)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.writeObjectField(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:1185)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor$DefaultFinalClassAccessor.write0(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:687)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor.write(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:157)
... 190 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Failed to write field [name=fd]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor.write(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:164)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.write(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:809)
... 197 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Failed to serialize object [typeName=java.io.FileDescriptor]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.write(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:840)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal0(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:223)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:164)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:151)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.doWriteObject(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:515)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.writeObjectField(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:1185)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor$DefaultFinalClassAccessor.write0(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:687)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor.write(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:157)
... 198 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Failed to write field [name=cleanup]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor.write(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:164)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.write(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:809)
... 205 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field jdk.internal.ref.PhantomCleanable jdk.internal.ref.PhantomCleanable.prev accessible: module java.base does not "opens jdk.internal.ref" to unnamed module @4dd87b51
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:340)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:280)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:176)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:170)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.<init>(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:300)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.registerUserClassDescriptor(BinaryContext.java:790)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.registerClassDescriptor(BinaryContext.java:762)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.descriptorForClass(BinaryContext.java:628)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal0(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:181)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:164)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:151)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.doWriteObject(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:515)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.writeObjectField(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:1185)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor$DefaultFinalClassAccessor.write0(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:687)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor.write(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:157)
... 206 more
```

Comment: There should be more error messages, please quote them in full. The stack trace that you have shared does not lead anywhere.

Comment: @alamar, have updated with fullstack trace, Please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to put a ClientCache object to cache, as some field of `com.wyse.stratus.server.cache.ConfigurationSchemaIgniteCache`.

It is a bad idea, please avoid putting Ignite internals to cache. You're not going to be able to use them if you get them from cache, anyway. If you must have such field in your POJO objects, you need to mark it `transient`.

It is also suspicious to me that you are trying to put something which looks like cache configuration to cache. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Thanks. After marking it as transient worked. The cacheableItems (objects) are legacy and its working fine on Memcached. But on Ignite its failing to.